# How to add share application button from activity to google+ and facebook?

Tags: android

I am building android application now i already completed, but I want to add Share button in root activity that user can share my application(link to download from google market) to google+ , facebook, twitter and linkin.

How can i do it?

## my code:

```
ImageButton sharingButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.share);
    sharingButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    sharingButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_share);

sharingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            { 
                shareIt();
            }
        });


private void shareIt()
{
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

I tried this but doesn't give me a result. Can you please help me?

regards,

Comment: Your code should share with anything that supports sharing plain text. If nothing else, on a production device, you should get SMS clients (e.g., Messenger), email clients (e.g., Gmail), Bluetooth, and perhaps others. Whether you get "google+ , facebook, twitter and linkin" is up to those who implemented those apps, not you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you prefere to do it by your self, with a library, you should use addThis : 
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381271-addthis-for-android-quickstart-guide

Answer (score 0):

These Couple of lines worked for me maybe you can try it :

```
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.google.com/");

    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subjecttest");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Choose option"));
```

I am also guessing that the button you have is getting clicked but the shareintent is'nt working, if there is an error before that part then maybe its not the shareintent but the button declaration and xml issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this in menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
          android:title="@string/share"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
    ...
</menu>
```

Read: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html